# Detecting Control + D in my code also triggers add bookmark keyboard shortcut in Chrome, is there any way to prevent this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome

Is there anyway to disable the browsers keyboard shortcut from going off too?  The google chrome keyboard shortcut happens AFTER my code.  i just dont want it to go off at all.

```
handleKeyDown( e ) {
if ( e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 68 ) {  // ctrl + d
    // this works, BUT it also triggers Google Chrome's bookmark shortcut  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should prevent the event's default action, like this:

```
function handleKeyDown( e ) {
  if ( e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 68 ) {  // ctrl + d
      // this works, BUT it also triggers Google Chrome's bookmark shortcut
      console.log('Ctrl+D');
  }
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a5wbd3o9/

Comment: Sure, no problem!